# How to prove a series converges if and only if its sequence of partial sums does as well?

Tags: real-analysis

If I had the sequence $(a_n)$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ where $b_n =  a_n - a_{n+1}$, I would like to prove that $b_n$ converges if and only if $(a_n)$ does as well. EDIT: Assume that $a_n \geq 0$.

Well I can see that looking at the first few terms for $b_n$, it will look something like this since it is a partial sum of the other:

$\sum_{n=1}^1 b_1 = a_1 - a_2$

$\sum_{n=1}^2 b_2 = a_1 - a_2 + a_2 - a_3$

$\sum_{n=1}^3 b_3 = a_1 - a_3 + a_3 - a_4$

So I can see that $\sum_{k=1}^n b_k = a_1 - a_{n+1}$ since all middle terms cancel. Then, I know that essentially, we can possibly use the definition of convergence for each partial sum so for example, the definition used in my textbook is:

The series $\sum a_n$ converges to s if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is N such that for all $n \geq N$, $|\sum a_i - s| < \epsilon$.

Would this mean that it would be sufficient to use this for one direction of the proof? Then how would I approach the other direction?

And one more thing: I am also curious as to whether $\sum b_n = a_1 - a_{n+1}$ would be the eventual sum of $b_n$.

Comment: I should specify that the sum is never negative.. sorry

Comment: I think your difficulties are caused by not being careful enough about notation.  When you write "the series $b_n = a_n - a_{n+1}$," I think you probably mean "the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$, where $b_n = a_n - a_{n+1}$."  When you write "$b_2 = a_1 - a_2 + a_2 - a_3$," I think you probably mean "$\sum_{n=1}^2 b_n = a_1 - a_2 + a_2 - a_3$."  When you write "$\sum b_n = a_1 - a_{n+1}$," you probably mean "$\sum_{k=1}^n b_k = a_1 - a_{n+1}$."  Clear up your notation and the answer to your question will become clear.

Comment: I did go and change my notation but it only made me more confused unfortunately.

Comment: Letting $B_m = \sum_{n=1}^m b_n$, it is *definition* that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges if and only if the sequence $\{B_m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ converges. And you've already shown that $B_m = a_1 - a_{m+1}$ for every $m$. Can you conclude that $\{B_m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ converges if and only if $\{a_m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ converges?

Comment: Can I conclude this by saying that since all ${a_m}_{m=1}^\infty$ converges that $B_m$ also converges? I feel like I am at the very end of making it work but just cannot manage to finish it.

Comment: Suppose $\{a_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ converges.  By definition, what this means is that there is some number $L$ such that $\lim_{m \to \infty} a_m = L$.  Now, can you compute $\lim_{m \to \infty} B_m$?

Comment: Would it just be L - $a_1$? Sorry, I don't think that's right..

Comment: It would be $a_1 - L$.